# How to create mongo view using pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, view, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am looking for a way to create a MongoDB 3.4+ view using `pymongo` from the following pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('parsed_tests').aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "raw_tests",
    localField: "repository_path",
    foreignField: "repository_path",
    as: "raw_data"
  }
}])
```

I want to do it in Python to have an initialization script in one piece. Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: Do you want to create a view with your the pipeline you passed to `.aggregate()`?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyMongo does not provide a `Database` method to create a view. However you can run the [`create`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/create/#dbcmd.create) command to create your view with the [command](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command) method. If fact [`createView`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/) is just a wrapper around the `create` command.

```
db.command({
    "create": "parsed_tests_view",
    "viewOn": "parsed_tests", 
    "pipeline": pipeline
})
```

Answer (score 4):

As sstyvane says, you'll need to give an explicit database command. Unfortunately, they got the syntax wrong.

This worked for me:

`db.command('create', 'parsed_and_raw_tests',
    viewOn='parsed_tests', 
    pipeline=my_pipeline)`

Also, if you've got a Mongo instance that upgraded from version 3.2 or earlier, you'll [need to set the feature compatibility version to 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) before you can create a view.

Answer (score 3):

As the [MongoDB documentation on views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/#create-view) suggests, the dedicated method `createView()` is merely a wrapper around the `createCollection()` method, which is present in `pymongo`.

In MongoDB, the creation process is expressed like this:

```
db.createCollection(
  "<viewName>",
  {
    "viewOn" : "<source>",
    "pipeline" : [<pipeline>],
    "collation" : { <collation> }
  }
)
```

In Python, you could achieve the same behaviour with the following code:

```py
# Assuming `db` is your database variable
db.create_collection(
    'parsed_tests_view',
    viewOn='parsed_tests',
    pipeline=[{
        '$lookup': {
            'from': "raw_tests",
            'localField': "repository_path",
            'foreignField': "repository_path",
            'as': "raw_data"
        }
    }]
)
```

More about the `create_collection()` method [in the docs of `pymongo`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.create_collection).